# Is Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY.compareTo(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) always 0

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that sorts objects of type `Float`. If a `Float` is null then I assign `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` to it and then compare. I wonder if 
`Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY.compareTo(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` always equals to 0

I wrote a test that does this comparisons and it returns 0. But I want to make sure that it always ZERO, knowing how tricky it is to compare floats.

Comment: why dont you try it?

Answer (score 0):

compare returns: the value 0 if f1 is numerically equal to f2; a value less than 0 if f1 is numerically less than f2; and a value greater than 0 if f1 is numerically greater than f2. So your comparison will always return zero.

Source from java documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo(java.lang.Float))